# What is the difference between [readability] and [code-readability]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process

[readability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readability):

> Readability is a subjective parameter used to measure an aspect of code quality. It is based on the assumption that code should be easily comprehensible by humans, both in its form and in its meaning.

[code-readability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-readability):

> Code-Readability is how easy it is to understand a piece of code. Whether it be reading someones code, or writing your own.

From the answer of a related meta question, [Code [readability] is very subjective](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317016/3416774), I guess that code-readability is more about meta-programming to analyze the code with tools, not with human eyes. However, even the answerer suggests that they are synonyms.

So are they? Should they be synonymized?

Comment: Are these tags belong on software engineering SE , and not SO ?

Comment: "Readability is a subjective parameter" - so questions regarding readability are primarily opinion-based anyways.

Comment: SO does not do `subjective`.

Comment: *"What is the difference between [readability] and [code-readability]?"* .... I dunno... maybe one's more readable than the other? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I'll play devil's advocate (even though I think I'm splitting hairs here and i'm of the opinion to synonymize/rid of them). I've viewed code that was properly spaced, indented, commas and brackets where they should be - it makes my life easy just scanning it with me eyes. however they make it difficult to actually *understand* the code. For example, what they chose to call their functions and variables - ever see var1, var2, var3 = var2? it makes tracing their work a nightmare. although it looks nice, it's a pain to actually walk through.

Comment: I think.. hum.. that one of the two is not about code? Ok, i know where the exit is.. -> []

Comment: @Kaddath what do you mean?

Comment: @Ooker I was just trying to make a "joke", *fails miserably and starts crying*

Comment: One is for comments/documentation and the other is for the code itself?

Comment: The fact that we can't seem to agree what these tag means, implies very strongly either that a) we don't know english b) in our context this meaning isn't concrete.

Comment: @lit Oh but they *do* do it [all the time]

Comment: Re: the validity of any `readability` post on SO, my argument would be that the readability has to (in some way) relate to the function / performance of the code. e.g. "Am i sacrificing performance by making this code block more legible?". The answer to that may be yes, no, or *yes, but here is a more legible **and** performative solution*. That IMO is valuable SO knowledge. Sheer readability is, as others suggest, very subjective.

Answer (score 1):

While the two do seem to be duplicates, IMO any question that has either one attached to it should probably be closed or moved to softwareengineering.SE; discussions about readability are precisely the sort of thing that belong there instead of here.  That makes me think we should burninate these tags instead.

Comment: Or code review. SO and softwareengineering.SE is mostly `!subjective // not subjective`

Comment: [Can we just leave it at "closed"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362417/1079354)

Comment: my recent question, [How to do addition operations intuitively with datetime in AutoHotKey?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55687860/3416774), does deal with readability, but still objective I suppose

Answer (score 0):

There are four main factors, in this order:

- Not using obscure and/or over-dense forms of code
- Formatting (this is why Python is so strong... a bit of enforcement... sad it's not a true compiled language, but hey)
- *Accurate* commenting (as opposed to the stuff originally written that no longer applies)
- Accurate and extensive documentation backing everything up

...most programmers fail at all four. In a minor defense, most employers push them to do things quickly, rather than well.

Comment: I see that you're answering the verbatim question.  This is a question about the *tags*.  Your answer is correct in the verbatim context, but not *this* one.